# PHP PDO statement throwing fatal error

Tags: php, pdo

I have a function which is throwing an unusual error regarding a syntax issue. Have a look.

```
public static function authenticate($_user, $_pass)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT password, key 
                FROM users 
                WHERE username = ' . $_user;

        $stm = Db::init()->prepare($sql);
        if ($stm->execute())
            return $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    }
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key FROM users WHERE username = testuser1' at line 1' in /class.php:111
>
> Stack trace:
>   #0 /class.php(111): PDOStatement->execute()
>   #1 /class.php(118): Password::authenticate('testuser1', 'test')
>   #2 {main} thrown in /class.php on line 111

Any ideas as to what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in sql. Surround it with backticks in your query. Like this:

```
public static function authenticate($_user, $_pass)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT password, `key` 
                FROM users 
                WHERE username = ' . $_user;

        $stm = Db::init()->prepare($sql);
        if ($stm->execute())
            return $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    }
```

BTW: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code. Use a parameterized query to bind the value of `$_user`.

Comment: Ah, ofcorse. I am obviously too new school. I get this after: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'testuser1' in 'where clause'' in /class.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /class.php(111): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /class.php(118): Password::authenticate('testuser1', 'test') #2 {main} thrown in /class.php on line 111`

Comment: That's because `$_user` doesn't have quotes around it.

Comment: @Asaph: I don't see why that would matter?

Comment: You could make that error go away by doing this: `$sql = 'SELECT password, \`key\` FROM users WHERE username = \'' . $_user . '\'';`, but you run the risk of SQL injection. Better to use a parameterized query and bind `$_user`.

Comment: @Headspin: It matters because your resultant query that the database runs (oversimplification, but stay with me) is `$sql = 'SELECT password, \`key\` FROM users WHERE username = testuser1;` and what you really want is `$sql = 'SELECT password, \`key\` FROM users WHERE username = 'testuser1';` See the difference?

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. There is no worry for sql injection with this one, but I guess that would defeat the purpose of preparing the statement anyways I guess. Thank you.